# WinRun4J - can't load library jars

Tags: java, winrun4j

I'm trying to execute my Java program as windows service using WinRun4J. The service is correctly created and run until it stop because of a ClassNotFoundException:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [appContext-webServices.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [spring/appContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/appContext-webServices.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/ContextFactory]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:271)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at br.com.gep.sped.extrator.AppServico.serviceMain(AppServico.java:22)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource     [spring/appContext-webServices.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/ContextFactory]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:255)
... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/ContextFactory]
at org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.getContext(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:326)
at org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.mapElementToJaxbProperty(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:352)
at org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.mapElementToJaxbProperty(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:294)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.spring.HttpConduitBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(HttpConduitBeanDefinitionParser.java:58)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:59)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1419)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1409)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: null
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:267)
at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:265)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:265)
at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:172)
at org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.getContext(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:321)
... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/ContextFactory
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.safeLoadClass(Unknown Source)
... 45 common frames omitted
```

I suspect WinRun4J isn't loading my lib jars that are in lib folder.
My application working dir is like this:

```
application directory
     -> bin directory
     -> lib directory
```

the main application jar is in bin folder, the others jars are in lib folder.
This is my servico.ini file, used by WinRun4J:

```
vm.version.min=1.6
single.instance=process
service.class=br.com.gep.sped.extrator.AppServico
service.id=AgenteWIN
service.name=Agente Win
service.description=Agente de extração dos dados SPED.
classpath.1=*.jar
classpath.2=../lib/*.jar
vmarg.1=-Xmn100M
vmarg.2=-Xms500M
vmarg.3=-Xmx500M
```

I've tryied a lot of variations in classpath.2 without success.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being Windows you probably need to use backslashes instead of forward slashes

```
classpath.2=..\lib\*.jar
```

If that isn't sufficient try adding

```
working.directory=.
```

to ensure that the relative paths are resolved against the right base directory.  If all else fails you could add a manifest to your main JAR file with a `Class-Path` that enumerates all the `../lib/file.jar` files and do away with `classpath.2` altogether.

Edit: seeing that stack trace it looks like WinRun4J is not setting up the thread context classloader properly. Try adding

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(
    AppServico.class.getClassLoader());
```

to the top of your `serviceMain`, before you instantiate anything Spring/CXF related.

Comment: still get the same exception (I've added it in the question). The mai jar already have a manifest file with classpath declaration.

Comment: @brevleq it looks like an issue with the thread context classloader (which is what the JAXB api tries to use to load the implementation classes). I've edited my answer with a possible workaround.